# persistence ignorance with ASP.NET identity framework and EF code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, poco

I developed my data layer with POCO classes and persistence ignorance principles in my mind. My code was like this

POCO class

```
 public class Report
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
   ...
    }
}
```

repository interface

```
 public interface IReportRepository
{
    IEnumerable<Report> GetAllReports();
    Report GetReport(int reportId);
 ...
}
```

and interface implementation with Entity framework code first, like

```
 public class EFReportRepository : BaseRepository, IReportRepository
{
    public EFReportRepository(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
    }

    public IEnumerable<Report> GetAllReports()
    {
        return DbContext.Reports.Include(r => r.AggregationParameters).Include(r => r.ErrorAttachment).Include(r => r.ExcelAttachment).Include(r => r.XmlAttachment).ToList();
    }

    public Report GetReport(int reportId)
    {
        return DbContext.Reports.Include(r => r.AggregationParameters).Include(r => r.ErrorAttachment).
            Include(r => r.ExcelAttachment).Include(r => r.XmlAttachment).SingleOrDefault(r => r.Id == reportId);
    }
```

everything work well until authorization(asp.net identity) was added.

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;

namespace DataRepository.Models
{
    public class MyUser : IdentityUser
    {
    }
}
```

Now every Report has User that created this report

```
public class Report
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
   ...
    public MyUser CreatedByUser { get; set; }
    public string CreatedByUserId { get; set; }
   ...
   }
}
```

Now i have tight dependency with entity framework which i wanted to omit, because of inheritance from IdentityUser class.

How can i exclude this dependency ? I will be thankful for any help )

**Update**
Now the problem is with creating UserManager object.
UserManager required IUserStore as input parameter. This interface has implementation in Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework namespace and is called UserStore, so my code was like this

```
manager = new UserManager<MyUser>(new UserStore<MyUser>(MyDbContext)).
```

But now MyUser class is not inherited from IdentityUser , so this code is broken(UserStore requires this type of class)

Comment: I have found [this](http://timschreiber.com/2015/01/14/persistence-ignorant-asp-net-identity-with-patterns-part-1/). Maybe will be helpful for somebody

Answer (score 2):

I used this approach which works fine as is;

```
namespace DataRepository.Models
{
    public class MyUser
    {
        public int Id { get; }
        //define other user properties
    }       
}

namespace SomeOtherNamespace
{
    public class MyIdentityUser : IdentityUser
    {
        private MyUser _User;

        public MyIdentityUser(MyUser user)
        {
            _User = user;
        }

        public int Id { get { return _User.Id; } }
        //define other IdentityUser properties by using the MyUser object
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Dion for help and for so late response(i was very busy at work and this task had low priority)

Comment: I tried to implement your idea but now i cannot use UserManager class from asp.net identity framework ... How do you do it ?

Comment: @Disappointed to be honest, I wrote my own. Can you update the question with how you have implemented the UserManager at this moment?

Comment: Before was usual code for creating UserManager(like in most tutorials)  manager = new UserManager<MyUser>(new UserStore<MyUser>(MyDbContext)). I could do it because class MyUser was inherited from IdentityUser(from Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework namespace), But now i cannot create UserStore class because my POCO class MyUser is not inherited from IdentityUser

Comment: @Disappointed then use `UserManager<MyIdentityUser>(new UserStore<MyIdentityUser>(MyDbContext))` ?